# Swift: SIGABRT error when Programmatically Performing Segue from an SKScene using NotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, segue, nsnotificationcenter

In the game I am making, I perform a segue from the view controller with my SKScene to the view controller with a UIView when you die. When I die, I make an action to make a fading up alpha of red over the scene. As soon as that is done, I want it to segue to the main menu. I am using the NotificationCenter to trigger the segue from a SKScene. I used a sequence SKAction to perform the segue as soon as the alpha is done scaling up. When I run this, the alpha scales up, then the screen stays the same, not changing ViewControllers. Once I close the app on my phone, I get a SIGABRT error on the line of code performSegue(), listed below.

**EDIT:** The error in the console is:
 Assertion failed: (*shader), function xglCompileShader, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Jet/Jet-2.20/Jet/xgl_utils.mm, line 24.

GameViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.doaSegue), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "doaSegue"), object: nil)

//I kept out all of the code for setting up the scene
}


@objc func doaSegue(){

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "show", sender: self) //The error occurs on this line
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    self.view = nil

}
```

Gamescene:

To see if it was happening because of the SKAction, I tried it without a SKAction(Code # 2), and the ViewController loaded, but no buttons I clicked in the view worked. After a while the SIGABRT error appeared on the same line.

Code # 1:

```
let Action1 = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0.75, duration: 5)

        let Action2 = SKAction.run {

            print("segue")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "doaSegue"), object: nil)

        }

        shape.run(SKAction.sequence([Action1, Action2]))
```

Code # 2:

```
// let Action2 = SKAction.run {

            print("segue")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "doaSegue"), object: nil)

      //  }

       // shape.run(SKAction.sequence([Action1, Action2]))
```

What do I do to stop getting this error. I made sure all of the segue was connected and the identifier was the same as in the code. What else would be making this error keep coming up.

I have an image of my storyboard if needed but I don't have enough reputation to post it.

Comment: Do you have an error message in debug console when it crashes?

Comment: Assertion failed: (*shader), function xglCompileShader, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Jet/Jet-2.20/Jet/xgl_utils.mm, line 24.